# Formula for this sequence of abs difference between any two digits of a three digit integer?

Tags: sequences-and-series

Take $234$ for example: abs diffrence between $2,3$ is $1$ ,  between $2,4$ is $2$ , between $3,4$ is $1$ , after sorted here get 112 in the sequence.

The sequence has 30 items :

```
 000, 011, 022, 033, 044, 055, 066, 077, 088, 099, 
 112, 123, 134, 145, 156, 167, 178, 189, 224, 235, 
 246, 257, 268, 279, 336, 347, 358, 369, 448, 459
```

Pattern of the sequence seems to be:

```
 (from  0 to  9) * 11 + 0

 (from 10 to 17) * 11 + 2

 (from 20 to 25) * 11 + 4

 (from 30 to 33) * 11 + 6

 (from 40 to 41) * 11 + 8
```

Comment: Your question and pattern isn't very clear. Some English would go a long way to clarifying it. What do you mean by "difference between any two digits of a three digit integer?" Based on the pattern at the top then then next line should be "(from 50 to 49)*11+10". Does the sequence here start decreasing?

Comment: The sequence only contains 30 items.

Comment: Take 234 for example: diffrence between 2,3 is 1 , between 2,4 is 2 ,  between 3,4 is 1 , here get 112.

Comment: Ok. So out of all numbers from 100 to 999 they fit into one of the patterns above where you've sorted from smallest to biggest. Given the shuffling involved there I don't imagine there is a nice pattern.

Answer (score 2):

If we take the pattern you've listed we can mathematically hammer it into a single formula but it won't be pretty.

Our aim is a sequence $a_x$ where $x$ ranges from $0$ to $29$ (easier to number it from zero than one but not hard to translate it).

Lets start looking at the 5 different brackets. We need to create a function which changes as:

$$\begin{array}{c}
x & \to & y & \to & i\\
0-9 & \to & 0-9 & \to & 0 \\
10-17 & \to & 10-17 & \to & 1\\
18-23 & \to & 20-25 & \to & 2\\
24-27 & \to & 30-33 & \to & 3\\
28-29 & \to & 40-41 & \to & 4
\end{array}$$

The formula changes at 10, 18, 24 and 28. These differ by 8, 6, 4 which means we need a quadratic relationship:

$$x_{change}=i(11-i)$$

Rearranging for $i$ and adding a floor function lets it work for all inputs $x$:

$$i=\bigg\lfloor\frac{1}{2}\left(11-\sqrt{121-4x}\right)\bigg\rfloor$$

Next we can look at the difference between $x$ and $y$. If $i=0,1$ then $y-x=0$. If $i=2$ then $y-x=2$. If $i=3$ then $y-x=6$. If $i=4$ then $y-x=12$.

The differences between the values $0,0,2,6,12$ are $0,2,4,6$ which again says we need a quadratic formula.

$$y-x=i^2-i$$

So rearranging for $y$, multiplying by $11$ adding on the $2i$ gives:

$$a_x=11y+2i$$

$$=11x+11i^2-11i+2i$$

$$=11x+11i^2-9i$$

$$=11x+i(11i-9)$$

$$=11x+\bigg\lfloor\frac{1}{2}\left(11-\sqrt{121-4x}\right)\bigg\rfloor\left(11\bigg\lfloor\frac{1}{2}\left(11-\sqrt{121-4x}\right)\bigg\rfloor-9\right)$$